Change texture of entity when you hover on it
I want make a code which is changes the texture of an entity when you hover on it. How to do it?
Suddenly, class Entity doesn't have a "highlight_texture" argument. I didn't find any questions with it on this website.
My code of my entity:
from ursina import *

app = Ursina()

class Door(Entity):
    def __init__(self, position=(0, 0, 0), blocked=False, parent=None):
        super().__init__(
            model='cube',
            position=position,
            texture=load_texture('assets/door'),
            scale=(2, 3.5, .1)
        )

        # This door must change its texture to 'assets/door_hovered'.


You can manually change door texture on mouse hover. Below is the simple example:
import ursina
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController

app = ursina.Ursina()
FirstPersonController()
floor = []
for x in range(10):
    for y in range(10):
        floor.append(ursina.Entity(parent=ursina.scene, model='cube', position=(x, -10, y), texture='grass', collider='box'))

door = ursina.Entity(parent=ursina.scene, model='cube', position=(5, -9, 5), texture='door', collider='box')
floor.append(door)


def update():
    if ursina.mouse.hovered_entity == door:
        door.texture = 'door_hover'
    else:
        door.texture = 'door'


app.run()


